# Exclude top and bottom 1% of data in a df in R

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
set.seed (1000)
a <- rnorm(1000)
b <- seq(1, 1000, by=1)
df <- data.frame(b, a)
```

I want to exclude the top 1% and bottom 1% of my data (column a).

I have read about trim and quantile in R but can't seem to get them to work.

Could someone help explain how I:

a. Set these extremities to NA

b. Delete these extremities off my dataframe

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? What's the trim function you used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if the elements of each column are in between the 0.01 and 0.99 quantiles, then keep rows where all columns are in between those quantiles with

```
keep <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, function(x) x >= quantile(x, .01) 
                                            & x <= quantile(x, .99)))


df[keep,]
```

If you only want to exclude rows where `a` is outside of the 0.01 and 0.99 quantiles, you can do

```
keep <- df$a >= quantile(df$a, .01) & df$a <= quantile(df$a, .99) 

df[keep,]
```

Or

```
keep <- lapply(df, function(x) x >= quantile(x, .01) 
                               & x <= quantile(x, .99))


df[keep$a,]
```

To set the extremes to `NA`, you can do this:

```
keep <- df$a >= quantile(df$a, .01) & df$a <= quantile(df$a, .99) 

df[!keep, 'a'] <- NA
```

`data.table` makes this much easier. For example, to keep rows where `a` is within the 0.01 and 0.99 quantiles, you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[a %between% quantile(a, c(.01, .99))]
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `dplyr::filter` and `dplyr::between` can be achieved as:

```
library(dplyr)

# Checking only for column a. Top 1% and bottom 1% is removed 
df %>% filter(between(a, quantile(a, .01), quantile(a, .99)))

# Checking for column a & b. Top 1% and bottom 1% is removed
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(between(., quantile(., .01), quantile(., .99))))
```