# Delete 5% percentile of a specific variable

Tags: r, outliers, percentile

So first all i know there are many topics about this but they alls seem to go about the whole dataset. But i want to have it applied to a specific variable and this is causing problems for me that were not addressed in the other threads.

So i want to delete 5% off (low end and high end) of the variable "cap".
This is what i tried.

```
attach(nuclear)

#variable cap in set nuclear, i want to delete (after inspecting the percentles) for example everything under 5% for cap only. 
quantile(cap, c(.025, .050, 0.25, 0.50, .95, .975)) 


quantile(nuclear$Point, 0.05)
nuclear$cap %>% filter(Point < quantile(nuclear$Point, 0.05))
```

This is what i got

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
 no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

> 

Comment: There are several errors in your code and what you want is unclear. What is the `Point` variable? It seems you want the following, without any of the "attach" business.
`nuclear %>% filter(cap > quantile(cap, 0.025), cap < quantile(cap, 0.975))`

Comment: Also, please consider creating a reproducible example in the future so that other users can run and debug your code and see the data you are using.

Comment: are you trying to keep the number of observations the same? or are you trying to filter (and therefore reduce the number of observations) of the whole data set?

Comment: This question asks about 1% not 5%, but it's the same thing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976407/exclude-top-and-bottom-1-of-data-in-a-df-in-r/50976526#50976526

Comment: @Puddlebunk yes i tried to reduce it, but i managed to edit the code to get this done. So thanks.

Comment: @luke.sonnet this is nuclear data, its integrated in R so everyone can see it.

Comment: @luke.sonnet Thank you so much for your code, that was exactly what i meant. I just couldn't figure out where the variable came into play. However i did get one sort of error when applied to my own dataset, but it still seemed to work I think. I got "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Comment: @luke.sonnet somehow that error did delete some of the data but not 5% and the upper boundary it didnt touch at all :S

Comment: Not sure I know how to help without more data.

Comment: i know.. its classified i cant show the original set. but somehow this line isnt working properly :( See if i can find another method.

Comment: Post the full error and post the actual line you used, you don't need to post the data. I need to see what error you've made.

Comment: Hi, I like to say that your solution worked but i made a mistake on my end. I executed it on a "value" not on the "dataset" I know... poor mistake. Anyway it works, i give you a an upvote and the case is closed :) thank you for your help luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to remove the values in a variable that are inside your cap then you could use a nested ifelse loop.

something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
nuclear %>%
mutate(cap = ifelse(cap > quantile(cap, probs = .95) |
                    cap < quantile(cap, probs = .5), NA, cap))
```

But if you want to filter the whole data set, then just use the same code but in filter rather than mutate.  hope this helps.

Comment: hmm seems to be something wrong with this code? some ")" and he can't find function "mutate" something i had never before.

Comment: fixed the missing ")".  This code is just an example. because i don't have your data i can't guarantee that his code will work for you to just cut/paste.  also, if you have not installed "tidyverse" you will need to do that first.

Comment: i used nuclear in this example which is free R data. And i did download this package still didn't work :(

Comment: It works now, i made a mistake on my end. For those who are interested, i accidentally made a value of the dataset and ran it on the "value" not on the set that's where it went wrong.